# Get performance data from Pyvmomi

Tags: python, vmware, vsphere, pyvmomi

I'm using the Python library for vsphere (pyvmomi) and I'm trying to get the performance data for a vm, this is the performance part:

```
    perfManager = content.perfManager
    metricId = vim.PerformanceManager.MetricId(counterId=6, instance="*")
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    endTime = datetime.datetime.now()

    query = vim.PerformanceManager.QuerySpec(maxSample=1,
                                             entity=host,
                                             metricId=[metricId],
                                             startTime=startTime,
                                             endTime=endTime)

    object = perfManager.QueryPerf(querySpec=[query])
    result = object[0]
    for child in result.sampleInfo:
        print(child)
```

However I'm not sure how to manipulate or even "read" this information, this is what I get when inspecting 'child':
[image]

How can this information be disclosed in a set of performance metrics?

Comment: I have the same question, and since this was from 3 months ago, do you know the answer?